# How to disable open keyboard after click in ClickableSpan

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannablestring

I have next code for adding in `EditText` image:

```
fun bind() {
            val ssb = SpannableStringBuilder(".")
            var bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.ic_rand_5)
            bitmap = resize(bitmap)
            val clickableSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
                override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
                    d { "ON CLICK" }
                }
            }
            ssb.setSpan(ImageSpan(context, bitmap), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
            ssb.setSpan(clickableSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
            etExp.setText(ssb, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)

    }
```

And after click on Image open keyboard, but i don't need this behavior. How disable auto open keyboard after click on `ImageSpan` with `ClickableSpan`?

Comment: have you tried simply calling `etExp.clearFocus();` after you set the text? Does that accomplish what you want?

Comment: @Silmarilos omg, why i not try such an obvious thing. thank you! pls, make answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the text into the EditText it gains focus and the system brings up the keyboard in response. The easiest way to get rid of the keyboard is to set the text like you did and then clear the focus afterwards:

```
//Set the ET
etExp.setText(ssb, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)

//Clear the focus:
etExp.clearFocus();
```

Hope that helps.